# Recovery datetime value in the edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

When i click in the edit view the datetime lost the value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Jym.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like, when i click in the edit view the value of DataNascimento recive the value from the database.

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: check whether the value is coming in Model.DataNascimento or not ?

Comment: not, the value is lost like in the image.

Comment: try below answer

Answer (score 0):

You must force the control to display to dd/mm/yyyy formatted date. to do this you need to format the date.decorate the date property in model as below

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime DataNascimento{ get; set; }
```

If you are using MVC5,this should work

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new {htmlAttributes = new {@Value = @Model.DataNascimento.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") } })
```

Comment: the datepiker display the correct format, but do not dysplay the value.